# How to remove posted date and author name from the_excerpt()

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress

In my website there is a social button for sharing post. It is working fine but I dont want post date and auther name in sharing content of facebook.. see image
[image]

as you can see in image marked by red line.

for sharing I am using it..

```
<!-- for Facebook -->          
                <meta property="og:title" content="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
                <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo($thumb_url); ?>" />

                <meta property="og:description" content="<?php the_excerpt(); ?>" />
```

for content I am using `the_excerpt()` but I dont want include date and auther name in content.

What can I do...
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

there are two ways you can do this thing possible

1. you can use a quick-fix to hide it with css, added to the end of style.css:

   .grid .post .post-meta { display: none; }
2. Delete the post-meta div from the thumbnail.

Thanks